# Why do I get an error when read or write more than 3 bytes using libusb to communicate with a PIC 18F2550?

Tags: c++, c, qt, pic, libusb

I'm using libusb in [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) to communicate with a PIC microcontroller, 18F2550. The thing is that it's working OK until I try to send or read more than three bytes. Why does it happen?

I've tried using bulk_read transfer and interrupt_read. When I put the size of the buffer equal or less than three, then the transmission works perfectly, using bulk or interrupt. When this size is greater than three, then I'm getting buffer[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) and buffer[2] OK, but the rest are wrong.

The error that I'm getting is from timeout. As input I'm using endpoint 0x81.

More information:

The return value from the bulk or interrupt read is -116. The numbers that I'm sending from the PIC to the PC in the two first bytes ([0] and [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29)) in hex is 0x02D6. With this number, `buffer[0]` = -42 (when it should be 0xD6 = 214) and `buffer[1]` = 2 that is correct.
In the `[2]` and `[3]` bytes the number is 0x033D, and I get `[2]` = 61 = 0x3D. That is correct and `[3]` = -42??? (like `[0]`).

And the fifth byte is 1, and the SW shows `2???`. Might it be a problem in the microcontroller, because I'm programming it as an HID USB?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that being a HID is the problem. I had a similar issue before; the PIC would randomly timeout when large data was being transmitted. It turned out to be some voltage fluctuation on the MCU. How are you connecting the crystal? Do you have a capacitor on VUSB to regulate it?

*[Building a PIC18F USB device](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Building_a_PIC18F_USB_device)* is a great tutorial on building a PIC HID, and even though it's not based on 18F2550 but on 18F4550, it should be quite similar, and I'm sure you can get a lot out of the schematics and hardware setup. It was the starting point for my PIC-USB projects.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried to "Vote Up" for your post but I have to get at least 15 reputation points to do that, lol. Even though the PIC is connected OK, (including crystal and VUSB cap.), checking the PICs timeout seems to be a really good idea. Another thanks for the link, seems to be a really good one.